# Designing a publisher/subscriber architecture

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, nservicebus, publish-subscribe

I was wondering if I can get some thoughts based on the following requirements:
- A service which polls a log table on multiple databases for changes and then publishes the notifications to any number of light weight clients running on various pcs
-The message sent would be small and would contain only data about maybe a timestamp of the event and nature of the event.
-I want the desktop client install on the pc to be very easy so don't want it to have huge reliance on 3rd party components apart from .net 4 framework.

Here's my own thoughts so far:
I have played around with NServicebus and this seems to fit the bill interms of what I want. 
I was thinking of polling the each database to be polled in the publisher using some sort of async methods and then creating the messages which the subscribers ( client ) would then recieve. 
Is Nservicebus too much for this?, at the moment I don't require the clients do nothing more than listen and receieve msgs so they would not really be sending anything back.
I realise, if I was to install NServicebus then MSMQ and other bits would then be required to be installed on each client too.
So hopefully these aren't resource hungry.
I have done a bit of reading and have downloaded bits of code to play around, but don't really have much experience in this area so any advice is usefull.

Comment: Have you looked at WCF Callbacks using netTcpBinding? Each client would have to register with the service but it is relatively easy to implement, lightweight and no 3rd party software needed.

Comment: @Lloyd, not properly no. I did look into full duplex services before for something else but guess it should something I should look at also

Answer (score 1):

What you describe can be achieved with pure .NET framework... IMHO NServiceBus is rather "too much" for what you describe...

To implement such a mechanism yourself you could use UDP broadcast... although UDP doesn't give a delivery guarantee it is usually reliable in LAN... only aspect you might need to take care of is to have a firewall rule allowing your UDP port...

As for the part with the DBs:

You don't say what sort of DBs those are... but some DBs (like SQL Server 2008, Oracle etc.) come with an event/notification mechanism which would make the polling part obsolete...

Comment: Thanks for your response, I plan to connect SQL Server 2008 dbs. However I would not be able to guarentee I would be able to use functionality like service broker on them, only thing I can be sure is that I will have read access to the table.

Comment: Also, the firewall issue maybe a factor too since I may have to work under the assumption, I won't be able to change any firewall settings. However, this may affect msmq too.

Comment: @Rubans If you can't change any firewall settings then you need to work with whatever connectivity option is available... so the question becomes what connectivity will be available at runtime (before deciding on the technology) ?

Answer (score 1):

The free license of NServiceBus permits only a single machine with 4 or fewer CPU cores for production use. The implication is that you cannot have a distributed model with this license*. Depending on your needs, you may need to purchase a commercial license.

NServiceBus is a very opinionated framework. If you're considering it, I would suggest doing a spike to see how hard it is to implement the functionality you need. You're likely to find it either dead easy (you're doing it in the NServiceBus way) or very frustrating.

[MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/) is decent, although the documentation is incomplete and there are some bugs. It's also designed to communicate only inside a firewall.

I like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) (it has a .NET client); consider evaluating it to see if it meets your needs. It does not do everything NServiceBus does, but you may not need the extra features.

P.S. If anyone suggests Rhino Service Bus, turn and walk away. Even the author admits that the documentation is "...spare to say the least."

*Disclaimer - I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: yes, valid point about the licence which I did read but guess for some reason I assumed my clients would be exempt from that. Surely, if you can only use install nservicebus on a single machine without a commercial use then it's not really useuable in distrabuted architectures without paying for it? Also, thanks for link about RabbitMQ, have heard of it but have yet to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i think this is a case for an ESB of some kind. The benefit that you get from using an established ESB (like MSMQ which NserviceBus uses) is that you get things like message durability.

I also think that using an ESB to handle the communication layer helps to improve the overall architecture of your solution by separating your two domains (publishing domain and consuming domain) a little more than you can with a custom network solution